# If $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ are ordered fields and $f$ is an isomorphism between them, then $f(0)=0'$ and $f(1)=1'$

Tags: proof-verification, ordered-fields

> If $\mathfrak{A}=\langle A,<,+,\cdot,0,1 \rangle,\mathfrak{B}=\langle B,<,+,\cdot,0',1' \rangle$ are ordered fields and $f:A \to B$ is an isomorphism between $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$, then $f(0)=0'$ and $f(1)=1'$.

Does my attempt look fine or contain logical flaws/gaps? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

$a+0=a \implies f(a+0)=f(a) \implies f(a)+f(0)=f(a)\implies f(a)+f(0)=f(a)+0'$. Cancel out $f(a)$ from both sides, we get $f(0)=0'$.

Take $a\in A$ such that $a>0$. Then $f(a)>0'$. We have $a\cdot 1=a \implies f(a\cdot 1)=f(a) \implies f(a)\cdot f(1)=f(a)\implies f(a)\cdot f(1)=f(a)\cdot 1'$. Since $f(a)>0'$, we cancel out $f(a)$ from both sides and get $f(1)=1'$.

Comment: I strongly believe that you are right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @SeewooLee!

Comment: There should be no need to use the ordering here. This is true for arbitrary fields.

Comment: I don't understand your idea @MattSamuel. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Well, first of all, any homomorphism of rings sends $0$ to $0'$. Any isomorphism of rings with identity sends $1$ to $1'$ as well.

Comment: Hi @MattSamuel, I got your points.